# How to highlight syntax in codeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to use [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) to my website a versatile text editor implemented in JavaScript for the browser. But the syntax highlight is not working. codeMirror Documentation didn't help me much. here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Code Mirror</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="codemirror.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <textarea id='demotext'>

    function foo() {
        for(i = 0, i < 10, i++)
        console.log(i);
    }

    </textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("demotext"), {
          lineNumbers: true,
          mode: "javascript"
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my code syntax inside textarea is not highlighting. 
[CodeMirror syntax highlighting is not working here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPgy7.jpg)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to load the mode for the language you want to highlight. In this case, load `mode/javascript/javascript.js` from the distribution.

Comment: In my case is not working. See this print screen: https://snipboard.io/TNDxut.jpg  I link those files from codemirror and I add **`<pre>`** and **`</pre>`** before and after java code lines. And it is not working,

Answer (score 1):

I just want write full scripts for the answer with step by step so for the newbie can follow along when want to test the full code how to implement codemirror.

### 1. Download [CodeMirror 5](https://codemirror.net/5/)

Make sure to [download codemirror](https://imgur.com/DFw6659) library from the website not from GitHub release.

### 2. CodeMirror as Vendor

As I write this, CodeMirror version is 5.65.14. ***Extract and rename*** the folder without version number.

### 3. HTML File

Write your HTML file parallel with codemirror folder. Don't create HTML file inside codemirror folder. I want to show in this code that we want to used CodeMirror as Syntax Highlighting for our website, not as code editor, so copy the code below:

```js
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Syntax Highlighting With CodeMirror 5</title>
        
        <link href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- CodeMirror Theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="codemirror/theme/yonce.css" />
        
        <script src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>

        <!-- add an add-on -->
        <script src="codemirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
        <script src="codemirror/addon/selection/active-line.js"></script>

        <!-- add mode of language that we want to syntax highlighting the code -->
        <script src="codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
        
    </head>

<body>

    <textarea id='kloningspoon-code'>

    function foo() {
        for(i = 0, i < 10, i++)
        console.log(i);
    }

    </textarea>

<script>
            CodeMirror.fromTextArea( document.getElementById("kloningspoon-code"), {
              readOnly: true,
              mode: "javascript",
              theme: "yonce",
              lineNumbers: true,
              matchBrackets: true,
              lineWrapping: true,
              cursorHeight: 0,
              styleActiveLine: true,
            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**

- *readOnly: true,* => we want to make the textarea not editable
- *mode: "javascript",* => the code that we want to syntax highlighting
- *theme: "yonce",* => theme for syntax Highlighting
- *lineNumbers: true,* => show line numbers
- *matchBrackets: true,* => so we know where are open and closing of the code
- *lineWrapping: true,* => make the textarea responsive on mobile browser
- *cursorHeight: 0,* => hide the cursor
- *styleActiveLine: true,* => show where line activated by cursor

I hope this can help.